# Merging TextView Above ImageView in a <merge> xml file android

Tags: android

In my application, I want the text to appear above the image view with padding 2 dp. But when I run the program the textview overlays the image. How can I make the image appear 2dp below textview using <merge> </merge>?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

    <ImageView

        android:id="@+id/item_image"
        android:layout_width="253dp"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/one_louisrossi" />

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fourty_eight"
        android:layout_weight="1.30"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="xxxxxx"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/eighteen"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</merge>
```

Comment: What layout type are you using? Linear or Relative?

Comment: its just a < merge > </ merge > tag

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356413/linearlayout-vs-relativelayout

Comment: Using a relative layout will let you position things above and below each other.

Comment: Merge is only used for grouping ViewGroups: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834898/what-is-the-purpose-of-androids-merge-tag-in-xml-layouts

Comment: If you want something to appear below like you said use linear layout.

Comment: not below but above, i need to use merge because i am doing a carousel

Comment: and it crash when i change the merge view to linear or anthoer layout view

Answer (score 0):

This is dependant on the parent container view from which you are including the merge.

Since you actually have an intended layout, I suggest you actually switch from a merge tag to a linear layout or relativelayout.

Answer (score 0):

To make the image appear below instead of appearing above it i would recommend a linear layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your TextView on ImageView then use `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout`.

The difference between FrameLayout and RelativeLayout is the first has different layer for view, so child views don't interact with each other

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageView

    android:id="@+id/item_image"
    android:layout_width="253dp"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/one_louisrossi"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
/>

<TextView

    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fourty_eight"
    android:layout_weight="1.30"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="xxxxxx"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/eighteen"
    android:textStyle="bold"
/>
```